# PHP: Extra spaces removed when using substr

Tags: php, isam

I am trying to separating data from Isam files looping it line by line using fgets and with substr to get correct data from correct position of line.

Source data:

```
000000124325424Productname    Type    Price    Weight    Unit    Unitcode
000000124325324Productname2   Type2   Price2   Weight2   Unit2   Unitcode2
```

Problem is that substr does not recocnize those extra spaces between data and therefore position of data is changing every line.

Substr is "seeing" line like this:

```
000000124325424Productname Type Price Weight Unit Unitcode
```

Is there any way to preserve the spaces between items?

Comment: what are you trying to `substr`?

Comment: Ex: product code 
$row .= ltrim(trim(substr ( $line,0,16)),'0');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After editing the question it hits me that you perhaps are dealing with a tab delimited string `\t`. Either way, sanitize each string before whatever you are trying to do with `substr()` :

```
$s = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $s);
```

This will strip out multiple blanks `"   "`=>`" "`, tabs `\t` and even line breaks.

---

Perhaps you can find `explode()` as a better approach after sanitizing :

```
explode(" ", str_replace("\t", " ", $line1))[0]
```

will always be first item, i.e product code without extra spaces.

Comment: That's correct, not spaces but tabs. 
preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $s) didn't work but replacing only tabs ($line = str_replace("\t", " ", $line1);) did the trick. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @RogerWayne - Weird, `/\s+/` works for me.  See update, perhaps you dont need `substr` after all, if all your lines has the same structure.  Just a suggestion. Thank you for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you display text in a web page, the web browser doesn't show multiple spaces as such. Try wrapping your text in a preformatting tag, like so

```
<pre>000000124325324Productname2   Type2   Price2   Weight2   Unit2   Unitcode2</pre>
```

Then the browser will render it with all the spaces shown.

You can troubleshoot this kind of problem using View Source... In your browser.

Comment: It is a given - but this helps `substr` to recognize extra spaces exactly ...how ?